# I am not able to set Alert for grafana graph

Tags: graph, alert, grafana, grafana-templating, grafana-alerts

I have set alerts for Disk usage and now I want set alerts for Memory usage but I am not able to set it is giving error `FAILED TO TEST RULE`. Axes B is used and Axes C is Total.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Previously I have added alert for disk usage and now trying to add for memory usage in same dashboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked my `Data Source` it was `$datasource` and I am using `influxDB` so I changed it to `influxDb`.

Comment: So there's no way to have a paramerized data source in an alert? I have multiple stacks to alert on.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of defining an `alert`, I think you are doing it correctly.

Looking at `Grafana`'s source code [here](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/master/pkg/api/alerting.go#L147). The error message "Failed to test rule" seems to be a nasty one as it is returning a http 500 code, which means "*internal server error*".

In other words, this is possibly a `Grafana` server bug. Probably raise it with the Grafana team [here](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues) with the steps to replicate.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to change the `avg()` in your Conditions.
Set it to `last()`. So it takes only the last value for your alert.

Comment: I tried it by changing `avg()` to `last()` but it is still giving me same error.

Comment: Are you using template variables in your Query B? If yes this could be the problem. I had the same issue. Grafana isn't able to do Alerting with template variables.
have a look at this: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/6557